# Sets, subsets, and elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone help me clear this up.

1. Is {0, 1} ∈ {0, {1}}
2. Is {0, 1} ⊆ {0, {0, 1}}
3. Is b ∈ {a, {a, b}}
4. And finally {a,b} ⊂ {a,a,b}

So I understand that a subset and proper subset (set without line under it) are different, because in a proper subset, A cannot be equal to B if A is a proper subset for B.

I think I'm mostly getting confused with how the set's break down to determine their elements, like for example in problem 1 is the sets elements {0, empty set, {{1}}, {{empty set}}}? So the cardinality would be 2?

Comment: Basic difefrence: $\in$ and $\subseteq$ are different relations. For an element $a$ of a set $A$ we have $a \in A$. For a subset $B$ of a set $A$ we have $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: $\{ 0,1 \}$ is **not** and element of $\{ 0, \{ 1 \} \}$ because the first is not "listed" between the elements of the second. The elements of the second are: $0$ and $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: only 4 is true and the rest are not

Comment: The condition for $B$ being a *subset* of $A$ is that every element of $B$ is also an element of $A$: for every $x$, if $x \in B$, then $x \in A$.

Comment: The elements of 1. are two: $0$ and $\{ 1 \}$. Thus $\{ 0,1 \}$ is **not** an element of the set.

Comment: Also the elements of 2. are two:  $0$ and $\{ 0,1 \}$. Thus, in order to check if $\{ 0,1 \}$ is a subset of the set, we have to check if every element of $\{ 0,1 \}$ is also an element of the set, and this is not.

Comment: Also the elements of 3. are two:  $a$ and $\{ a,b \}$. Thus, $b$ is not an element of the set.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The elements of {0, {1}} are 0 are {1}. Neither of these are equal to {0,1}, so {0,1} is not an element of {0, {1}}.
2. To determine whether {0,1} is a subset of {0, {0,1}}, you must ask whether every element of {0,1} is an element of {0, {0,1}}. This is not the case, since 1 is an element of {0,1}, but 1 is not an element of {0,{0,1}}; the elements of {0,{0,1}} are 0 and {0,1}, neither of which are 1.
3. The elements of {a,{a,b}} are a and {a,b}. Are either of these equal to b?
4. It is true that {a,b} is a subset of {a,a,b}. The elements of {a,b} are a and b, and both of these are in {a,a,b}. However, it is also true that {a,a,b} is a subset of {a,b}, for the same reason. The fact that a appears twice is irrelevant; it only matters whether or not it is there. To summarize, {a,b} is a subset, but not a strict subset, of {a,a,b}.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation

Comment: for question 3, had the question been {b} ∈ {a, {a, b}}, would this have been true? Because the elements of the second set are a and {a,b}, which {b} is a part of the element {a,b}.

Comment: No, because {b} is not equal to {a,b}.